# Break on WebSocketExceptions in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

I wanted to make Visual Studio break on al System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketExceptions, but they don't appear in the Exception Settings pane. 
[image]

Is there a way to add WebSocketExceptions to the list here? Or am I stuck just breaking on all types of exceptions

Comment: Isn't that what the big green '+' is for?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. In my defense, the '+' isn't enabled unless you have selected a category, so I didn't notice it or think to try it.